# Listado con "dir" en ruta absoluta y ruta relativa

Tags: windows, consola

Estoy tratando de hacer un listado de los archivos dentro de C y sus subdirectorios cuyo tercer carácter sea 's' y cualquier extensión:

Esta primera opción si me ha funcionado

```
C:\>dir ??s*.* /s
```

Pero usando una ruta absoluta desde la carpeta 'SISTEMAS' no me funciona

```
C:\SISTEMAS>dir C:\ ??s*.* /s
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal en la segunda opción?

Comment: ¿Es posible que tengas un espacio despues de `C:\`? tendría que ser: `C:\??s*.*`. Curiosamente esto funciona en la consola de comandos de windows pero no en Power Shell.

Comment: @SuperG280 tiene razón.  Quiere dir C:\??s*.* /s

Comment: @Duston Muchas gracias! justo ese jodido espacio era el problema. kwento!